# How do I get data from sharepoint list in webpart in spfx

Tags: spfx-webparts

I have make one web part in spfx, I am able to fetch values of all columns of sharepoint list except one which is of type person or group, In this column there are multiple names I want to fetch all names of that particular column, how can I do this? In my webpart under that column it is showing UNDEFINED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$expand` to get additional details from the People field.

Assuming that you need details of `Author` field, modify your endpoint as below:

```
`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items?
$select=Title,ID,Author/Title,Author/Department,Author/EMail&$expand=Author`;
```

So, in your method it will be used as :

```
var endPointUrl = `${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items?$select=Title,ID,Author/Title,Author/Department,Author/EMail&$expand=Author`;

this.context.spHttpClient.get(endPointUrl,SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)  
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {  
        response.json().then((responseJSON: any) => {  
          console.log(responseJSON);  
        });  
      });
```

Reference -

[Get details from Person or Group fields](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31210.sharepoint-2013-get-user-details-from-person-or-group-field-using-rest-api.aspx)

Comment: hey @deeksha , did you try this? If its working, could you please mark it as answer ? Its just a checkmark besides the answer

Comment: In export interface ISPList{person or group column will be of string type only}?

Comment: yes, please see the JSON values and then create your interface accordingly

Comment: I am still getting error for my person or group column, under that column value it is showing [object Object]